# Returning response from multiple jQuery Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have this JS code. I'm trying to reach the total length of the `dataJson` object after doing multiple Ajax calls. When I try the calls seperately, they return the correct number (60, 64 and 5).

When I combine the calls using `when`, I get 60, 64 and 64 as a count. Any idea why does it happen like this? I would appreciate any help.

```
var publicationData = new Array();
var researchers = [];
var year = [];
var title = [];
var pub = [];

var dataJson = [];
callServerAsync();

function callServerAsync(){

    var p1 = $.get('Year2013.html').then(function(responseData) {

        return handleData(responseData); //count returns 60

    });
    var p2 = $.get('Year2014.html').then(function(responseData) {
        return handleData(responseData); //count returns 64

    });
    var p3 = $.get('tauchi_publications.html').then(function(responseData) {

        return handleData(responseData); //count returns 5

    });

    return $.when(p1, p2, p3).then(function(result1, result2, result3){

        //count returns 60, 64, 64

    });
}
function handleData(responseData){

    var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
    htmlObject.innerHTML = responseData;
    pub = htmlObject.getElementsByClassName("julkaisu");

    getPublicationData(pub);
    getResearchersYearTitle(publicationData);
    dataJson = createJson(researchers,year,title);

    var count = Object.keys(dataJson).length;
    console.log(count);

    return dataJson;

}

function createJson(researchers,year,title){
    var dataJson = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < researchers.length; i++){
        dataJson.push({ "Researchers": researchers[i],
            "Year": year[i],
            "Title": title[i]
        });
    }
    return dataJson;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle.

Comment: There are more than one html pages. I don't know how to add those pages to Fiddle.